# ImageView Object Always Null

Tags: android, imageview

I have a very simple Android activity layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView id="@+id/blaimg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I do the following from `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blaimg);
```

the contents of `imgView` is always null!
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your ImageView declaration to::

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/blaimg"     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Haha I had to keep looking till I saw the difference.
  
id -> android:id

Comment: Ah for pete's sake, that indeed whas the whole problem! Dammit. Well thanks a lot! I think I've been looking at least 2 hours to see what was wrong.